# Windows 8 not booting after manually upgrading to 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on top of my previous 13.10 Ubuntu installation. I did it manually by formating the mount and home folders without touching the Windows partition. Apparently it didn't detect the Windows OS.

But there is a 'Windows boot manager (on /dev/sda2) entry on the grub menu but it doesn't do anything. I can only boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Read [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

I faced that problem when  I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside my pre-installed Windows 8.

After installing Ubuntu I ran the recommended repairs in [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). However, the grub menu disappeared and my laptop booted straight to windows 8. Inside windows I opened a command prompt as administrator and typed in this command exactly as it is:

bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi

After it concludes successfully just restart your computer and grub should turn up with functional boot for both Windows and Ubuntu.

I strongly recommend reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) though. (if you have not already)

A small tip when installing Ubuntu using the “Something else” option, create a swap partition (if you have not done that already) that is twice your RAM size at least. If you have an SSD then just forget the swap partition.

Comment: For additional information, I have turned off secure boot before installing so I wouldn't have to deal with UEFI. Will this make a difference?

Comment: Well sometimes it works with Secure Boot enabled. If it does not (which is also what happened with me), then just turn it off and everything should would itself out. Disabling Secure Boot and disabling UEFI are two very different things. In most cases windows 8 works with Secure Boot disabled but it will never work with UEFI disabled.

Comment: I still can't boot into Windows, even though I used boot-repair. It didn't bring any changes, things are still the same as before including the grub menu.

Comment: What kind of Partitioning Scheme do you have? MBR or GPT?

Answer (score -1):

Boot into Ubuntu. Terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot.  This should auto detect all boots and rebuild Grub.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work.